# NgModelChange on input number not updating the view

Tags: angular, input, angular-ngmodel

I'm currently trying to create an input number that prevent user to enter a number that is higher than a @Input() maxValue, I implemented it like this :

HTML :

```
<input
    class="number-selector-input"
    type="number"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    (ngModelChange)="checkValue($event)"
/>
```

Typescript :

```
public checkValue(value) {
  if (value > this.maxValue) { 
    this.value = this.maxValue;
  }
  if (value < this.minValue) { 
    this.value = this.minValue;
  }
}
```

It is working quite well but there is still a problem that I can't understand. I have a maxValue equals to 100, when I type 150 or 200, it change automatically to 100 but when I type 1000, the input number does not update.

When I tried to show the value in the console or directly in the HTML, the model is correctly equals to 100. Do you have any idea to help me understand this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird bug to be honest, I tested and it showed the same behavior.

However, you can circumvent this by adding a directive, which is imo also a lot cleaner because it doesnt clutter your component with a function

Directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[minMax]'
})
export class MinMaxDirective {

  @Input()
  public min: number;

  @Input()
  public max: number;

  constructor(private ref: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('input', [ '$event' ])
  public onInput(a_Event: InputEvent): void {
    let val = parseInt(this.ref.nativeElement.value);
    if(this.max !== null && this.max !== undefined  && val >= this.max)
      this.ref.nativeElement.value = this.max.toString();
    else if (this.min !== null && this.min !== undefined  && val <= this.min)
      this.ref.nativeElement.value = this.min.toString();
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
<input
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    [min]="minValue"
    [max]="maxValue"
    minMax
    class="number-selector-input"
    type="number"/>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-min-max-directive

Comment: Oh thank you for your answer, I found another solution but yours seems better !

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
<input
        class="number-selector-input"
        type="number"
        [(ngModel)]="value"
        (ngModelChange)="checkValue($event)"
    />
    
    public checkValue(value) {
      if (+value > this.maxValue) { 
        this.value = this.maxValue;
      }
      if (value < this.minValue) { 
        this.value = this.minValue;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, it's not working either

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve my problem by using (keyup) instead of (ngModelChange) :

```
(ngModelChange)="checkValue($event)" --> (keyup)="checkValue($event)"
```

And the checkValue(value) method became :

```
public checkValue(event) {
  if (event.target.value > this.maxValue) {
    this.value = this.maxValue;
  }
  if (event.target.value < this.minValue) {
    this.value = this.minValue;
  }
}
```